# How do you wrap text around a figure inside an enumerate list structure?

Tags: wrapfigure

My example is this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{lociplanarsetsedited.eps}
        \caption{A caption}
        \end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec erat libero, varius ut lacinia eget, fringilla sit amet nibh.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

The image I'm using comes from the graph of a planar set at https://sites.google.com/site/xtheunknown0/latex. I'm not sure how to get the eps up (but I converted the file first, of course).

So as you should be able to see, the image comes at the end of the document.
How do I put the graph to the right of the (1) and have the two sentences of Latin underneath the graph?

Comment: For a minimal working example, instead of `lociplanarsetsedited.eps` use some of the images of the  `mwe` package, like  `example-image-a`, so everyone can compile your code without mess with search & download images.

Comment: i'm not sure what the `\begin{enumerate}` after `\item` is intended to do.  in any event, `\wrapfigure` doesn't play well with any kind of list.  from the `wrapfig` documentation: "You must not specify a `wrapfigure` in any type of list environment or immediately
before or immediately after one."  (there are other important warnings in the documentation; read it -- `texdoc wrapfig`.)  do consider using a minipage, which can be adjusted to align properly with the item index.

Answer (score -2):

Environment `wrapfigure` does not work under `enumerate` environment.

My code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth} %this figure will be at the right
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{knuth.png}\\
    \caption{knuth}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                      adipiscing elit. 
             Donec erat libero, varius ut lacinia eget,
             fringilla sit amet nibh.\\
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                      adipiscing elit. 
             Donec erat libero, varius ut lacinia eget,
             fringilla sit amet nibh.\\
 \vspace{1cm}
  \noindent
 \begin{center}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result1]

The picture can be either set to right turn side or left turn side as you like by changing the wrapfigure option.

The answer has already appeared in TeX.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).